# Facebook error “App not setup:still in development mode”

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, authentication

I am trying to create a facebook login and i tried to implement the same steps as specified in the Firebase web site. when the facebook login button is clicked an error saying.
" App not setup: This app is still in development mode, and you dont have access to it.Switch to registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions"

I know many people asked this. and the answer for resolving this error is to set the app as public in developers account. but my issue is where to set it. all the answers are outdated as the facebook developers account page have been changed and there is lot of changes and i could not locate it or fix it.
 thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to add privacy policy url in Facebook developer dashboard .

Answer (score 2):

While your app is in development mode you can test the Facebook login using the account in which you have created an app.

If you try to test Facebook login in your app in development mode then you have to use the account in which the app is created. Using other Facebook accounts will not work for testing Facebook login in development mode.

**You must need to specify the Privacy policy URL in order to make your app status live on Facebook developer console.**

You will not able to make status live unless you specify the privacy policy URL.

Comment: Thanks Mahendra. I am trying to integrate facebook login via firebase. but i am getting lot of error . the google results are having outdated class references. could some one recommend the latest steps to follow to incorporate the facebook login in my swift app

Comment: Here is a good tutorial: https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-facebook-login/

Comment: but this error is coming before even i am logging in . so how to try with the registered facebook login

Comment: actually it didnt work even with the registered facebook login . its throwing error even before the login screen

Answer (score 1):

Go to [Facebook Developer Dashboard](https://developer.facebook.com) and turn this on and check if **Status** is **Live**

[image]

Comment: i am trying to switch on it. but its asking for a valid URL. so what should i give in the Privacy Policy URL. but before doing all these, the status is in development. i atleast need for testing it.

Comment: You need to provide your app privacy policy url if you don't have any website or privacy policy then you can generate from here (https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/). It's mandatory to provide PrivacyPolicy in order to **Live** your App.

Comment: i tried creating a privacy policy via the link you have shared. but i am receiving the below error while i save changes with the Privacy policy Link generated. "You must submit a valid Privacy Policy URL in order to be compliant with Facebook Platform. Request failed with error: Bad Response Code: URL returned a bad HTTP response code."

Comment: @uma there are many other websites which are providing this service. I am personally using this [https://www.termsfeed.com/] go ahead and try this or if you have your server or website deployed somewhere you can host your privacy policy there.

Answer (score 0):

I created a tester in the roles section of Facebook developer dashboard. The FB id added as tester should accept the request which is pending. then the above error didnt appear and it worked for me. (This solution is for those who wants to just test the app and not make it live.)

Answer (score 0):

Allow these permissions from your created FACEBOOK App:

[image: FB app permissions]

Comment: @Calculuswhiz: It looks like this was a link to an image, not a link to a webpage.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Yes. I see. For the author of this answer, it would be be better to add a description of your image too for the users that can't see images.

Comment: To solve all problems above, please avoid images as much as possible. In this specific case, you could just list, textually, the permissions that need to be enabled. I don't see any reason to use an image here...